# Django: Translations not working on S2. Path issue?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I have added some translation for my website (running django 1.8) that work fine locally but are not working when deployed.

I've checked if the .mo and .po files were commited (They were)
and if the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` had been setup correctly (they were / see below)

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

)

Since its working just fine locally (and I've commited the .mo and .po' files) I am beginning to suspect that the issue is that DJango is unable to find the files on the server, but I cannot see how - as my settings should account for this.

Here is my `LOCALE_PATHS` setting:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),)
```

and below is the folder structure on my locale computer

```
src
  | 
  |- root
  |- locale
  |     |---fr
  |          |-LC_MESSAGES
  |                      |
  |                       |- django.mo
  |                       |-django.po
  |
  |-static    
  |-app1
  |-app2
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's permissions issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Could you elaborate? Do you mean that the .mo / .po files have to be executable ?

Comment: No, I mean that the server process cannot access directory/file.